# PostgreSQL random performance hit on simple queries

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, database-performance

We have a bunch of java REST services which uses local database for various use-cases. We have noticed that, while stress testing these services (20 concurrent clients making various requests), some of the requests (roughly 10 out of 1000) take about 5-10 seconds while the average is 50-100 milliseconds.

I have isolated the issue down to the database operations. These are all very simple operations on small/empty tables. So, I have done the following to get more info:

- Set JDBC connection pool's `setMaxWait` setting to 1 second, in order to catch pool queue issues. No exception has been thrown yet.
- Set `deadlock_timeout` setting to 200 milliseconds and enabled `log_lock_waits` on ***postgresql.conf*** file in order to catch if there is any lock causes this. I've seen no such logs in postgresql.
- Enabled and set `log_min_duration_statement` to 1500 milliseconds to make sure the database operations were indeed the cause. A sample (`gce_resolver` is an empty table at this point):

  > 2017-08-09 10:15:21 CEST LOG duration: 1597.000 ms  bind : /* SiteDao.getAllGceResolvers */ SELECT * FROM gce_resolver ORDER BY name
- Sounds like unrelated but just to be sure, enabled `log_autovacuum_min_duration` by setting it to `0`. No relevant logs were produced at the time of the stress testing.
- Enabled `auto_explain` and set the `auto_explain.log_min_duration` to 1000 as well as `auto_explain.log_verbose` to `on`. A sample:

  ```
  2017-08-09 10:20:59 CEST LOG:  duration: 2881.699 ms  plan:
  Query Text: /* UserLicenseDao.insertLicense */ INSERT INTO user_license (user_dn, created) VALUES ($1, $2)
  Insert on public.user_license  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
          Output: NULL::integer, 'CN=user172,OU=local'::text, '2017-08-09 10:20:56.153'::timestamp without time zone
  ```

It's a very simple insert, which looks like it *cost* very little, but somehow took almost 3 seconds for some reason. Now I'm out of ideas. What could be causing this delay? And why sometimes?

PostgreSQL 9.4.12

Comment: it could be locks (not deadlocks - just locks) - do you see `waiting = true` in `pg_stat_activity` sometimes?..

Comment: Do you have some hotdumps or periodic backups?

Comment: @VaoTsun documentation says for `log_lock_waits`: "Controls whether a log message is produced when a session waits longer than deadlock_timeout to acquire a lock. This is useful in determining if lock waits are causing poor performance."
So I was hoping for that log but never happened. I'm checking the locks on pgadmin-server status during the test and it seems all locks are granted. Hard to follow those though.

Comment: @partlov no, no backups or hotdumps.

Comment: do you observe IO pikes while this happens?.. maybe "checkpoints are occurring too frequently" in logs?

Comment: IO usage is high during the test and some pikes occur but I can't say I can see direct correlation between the spikes and the occurrences. No checkpoint related logs during the test. There are `checkpoint complete` logs when the system is idle. By the way, just even saw this:

`2017-08-09 11:39:05 CEST LOG duration: 1577.000 ms  parse <unnamed>: /* Health Check */ SELECT 1`

Comment: Can you try to do test with postgresql installed on other machine/server? It happened to me these strange performance issues from time to time with corrupted disk.

Comment: Well, this was happening on our test environment with isolated network and test-only linux machines. Now I'm actually reproducing it on my Windows local workstation. But that's a good point, I'll try on another just to make sure.

Comment: well, turns out we can't reproduce it on other machines or that test environment anymore. It was very consistent with the test environment before. I guess corrupted disk is the most likely suspect now.

Comment: You can turn on log_checkpoints and see if you're getting them when you see this.